# Variable setting from InitInstance()?

Tags: visual-c++

In my InitInstance() in ProjectNameApp I would like to set a CSring variable that will be used in ProjectNameView.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Thank you in advance.
a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MFC provides the global function AfxGetApp() which returns a pointer to your CWinApp object. Cast that pointer into a pointer to your app class, then it can be used to access public members of that class.

```
#include "YourApp.h"

CString s = ((CYourApp*)AfxGetApp())->m_appCString;
```

Comment: Thank you- Can you please give me an example of how to do this?